# How to use JCurses in Eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jcurses

I'm trying to develop a program that simulates the **Terminal** in Linux. My problem is that I can't clear the screen in the default Eclipse console.

After a lot of searching, I've found a library called **JCurses** that can do the task. But I can't get it working in Eclipse.

I've searched for a tutorial, but it seems there is not.

Can any one help me how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found it.

I have used an external Java console. It's called **Eric**:
http://cs.roosevelt.edu/eric/console.html

It's very easy to use. It could be run flawlessly on Eclipse although it's said to be for Netbeans only.

Thanks guys very much

Comment: This didn't work for me in Windows, but another [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20452886/511976) did.