# How do I set up a Jcurses library?

Tags: java, eclipse, jcurses

I am trying to use the Jcurses library for coding a Rougelike. I was wondering how specifically I should set up Jcurses so that I can compile and write classes that access it. (I'm using Windows.) So far I have tried including the library in Eclipse, but following the normal process for including libraries resulted in errors. What should my directories look like (in relation to where the Jcurses folder is stored and where my project is stored) when everything is set up, and which paths do I need to set?

PS: I found that a similar question had been asked but it appeared to offer an alternative to Jcurses, not how to use Jcurses.

Comment: I would personally suggest this library here. One simple jar file, import it into Eclipse, and you're done. https://github.com/trystan/AsciiPanel

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the Jcurses for your platform (available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/files/javacurses/0.9.5b/) that is `jcurses-windows-0.9.5b.zip`. Next, to install do these steps (from [ECLIPSE_JCURSES_HOWTO.txt](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/javacurses/ECLIPSE_JCURSES_HOWTO.txt?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fjavacurses%2Ffiles%2FECLIPSE_JCURSES_HOWTO.txt%2Fdownload&ts=1386501782&use_mirror=softlayer-dal)) -

If you know which command Eclipse uses to launch your program, start at step 4.

Step 1) Run Java app as usual (it does not matter if it fails), and switch to the debug view.

Step 2) Right click on the process, and open the property window by selecting "Properties".

Step 3) Select and copy the command-line parameter used to launch the program.

Step 4) Hit the arrow-button next to "External Tools" (The play icon with a small red toolbox), and hit "External Tools Configuration"

Step 5) Create a new configuration, with the following data:

```
Location: The path to the cmd.exe of your Windows OS.
  For Example: C:\WINXP\system32\cmd.exe

  Working Directory: Whatever working directory you want.

  Arguments: "/c start C:\WINXP\system32\cmd.exe /k " followed by the previously copied command.
  For Example:
    /c start C:\WINXP\system32\cmd.exe /k C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\mccae\Eigene Dateien\javawork\TWCC+\bin" at.co.lipski.twcc2.console.TWCCDaemon
```

Comment: I'm using a VM with Debian 8 and IntelliJ as IDE, is there a way to use JCurses with this configuration ?